# Change line width getting error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance

I want to be able to change the line width but I seem to be running into a bit of a problem. The way I have it set up is that I have 6 different line widths and when a user clicks on a width it should be reflected the next time they draw a line. Currently I’m getting the error:

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object BrushWidth.SetThickness (Int32 _lineNum) (at Assets/_Scripts/BrushWidth.cs:46) BrushWidth.Start () (at Assets/_Scripts/BrushWidth.cs:30)”

which is referring to the line that changed the line scale, lineConfig.Scale = 0.35f ;

What am I missing here? I thought I made my instance reference with public LineConfig lineConfig ; Thanks for the help!

```
using UnityEngine ;
using System.Collections ;
using UnityEngine.UI ;
using System ;
using PaintCraft.Tools ;

public class BrushWidth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6 ;
    public float brushSize ;
    public Text brushNameTextBox ;
    public String brushName ;
    public LineConfig lineConfig ;

    void Awake ()
    {
        lineConfig = gameObject.GetComponent<LineConfig> () ;

        btn1.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (1)) ;
        btn2.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (2)) ;
        btn3.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (3)) ;
        btn4.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (4)) ;
        btn5.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (5)) ;
        btn6.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (6)) ;
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        // Set Starting Thickness
        SetThickness (3) ;
    }

    void SetThickness (int _lineNum)
    {
        switch (_lineNum)
        {
            case 1:
                lineConfig.Scale = 0.1f ;
                brushName = "Thin  " ;
                break ;
            case 2:
                lineConfig.Scale = 0.2f ;
                brushName = "Light  " ;
                break ;
            case 3:
                lineConfig.Scale = 0.35f ;
                brushName = "Regular  " ;
                break ;
            case 4:
                lineConfig.Scale = 0.5f ;
                brushName = "Medium  " ;
                break ;
            case 5:
                lineConfig.Scale = 0.75f ;
                brushName = "Thick  " ;
                break ;
            case 6:
                lineConfig.Scale = 1.0f ;
                brushName = "Heavy  " ;
                break ;
            default:
                break ;
        }
        brushNameTextBox.text = brushName ;
    }
}
```

Comment: NO! `Awake()` gets executed before `Start()`

Comment: @user3185569 Awake is called then Start is called. @OP Drag a GameObject with `LineConfig` attached to to it to the `lineConfig` slot.

Comment: Add `[RequireComponent (typeof (LineConfig))]`attribute before BrushWidth script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that you don't have a `LineConfig` component attached to the object your script is attached to.  Because of this, `GetComponent` returns null.  To fix this issue, add a `LineComponent` to your object, or simply change:

```
lineConfig = gameObject.GetComponent<LineConfig> () ;
```

to:

```
lineConfig = gameObject.AddComponent<LineConfig>() ;
```

Or, if you want to make sure there is a `LineConfig` already attached, add `[RequireComponent (typeof (LineConfig))]` to the beginning of your class, above `public class BrushWidth : MonoBehaviour`.
So, your class should look like this:

```
using UnityEngine ;
using System.Collections ;
using UnityEngine.UI ;
using System ;
using PaintCraft.Tools ;
public class BrushWidth : MonoBehaviour
{
public Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6 ;
public float brushSize ;
public Text brushNameTextBox ;
public String brushName ;
public LineConfig lineConfig ;

void Awake ()
{
    lineConfig = gameObject.AddComponent<LineConfig> () ;

    btn1.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (1)) ;
    btn2.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (2)) ;
    btn3.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (3)) ;
    btn4.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (4)) ;
    btn5.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (5)) ;
    btn6.onClick.AddListener (() => SetThickness (6)) ;
}

void Start ()
{
    // Set Starting Thickness
    SetThickness (3) ;
}

void SetThickness (int _lineNum)
{
    switch (_lineNum)
    {
        case 1:
            lineConfig.Scale = 0.1f ;
            brushName = "Thin  " ;
            break ;
        case 2:
            lineConfig.Scale = 0.2f ;
            brushName = "Light  " ;
            break ;
        case 3:
            lineConfig.Scale = 0.35f ;
            brushName = "Regular  " ;
            break ;
        case 4:
            lineConfig.Scale = 0.5f ;
            brushName = "Medium  " ;
            break ;
        case 5:
            lineConfig.Scale = 0.75f ;
            brushName = "Thick  " ;
            break ;
        case 6:
            lineConfig.Scale = 1.0f ;
            brushName = "Heavy  " ;
            break ;
        default:
            break ;
    }
    brushNameTextBox.text = brushName ;
}
}
```

Hope this helped :)